# How pull a select html formatted chunk of a google spreadsheet using a URL

Tags: database, web, google-sheets-api

I have a tree farm.
I have a Google spreadsheet that has my inventory in the form that I took it.

I have  pivot table that summarizes that sheet.

How can I run a query from the Jack Pine description page on my website that pulls the appropriate blob off the pivot table on the spreadsheet?

Here's what I've done so far:

1. Create a new spreadsheet that does an importrange() from the individual sheet with my pivot table.
2. Share to the world, published to the web.  Using another browser where I am not logged in with my google ID I can see the file, and it is view only.

   https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13pXb7Kek010B6s8Ez3h6yX4qF92MgvV4uMk71dJhe3o/edit#gid=0

I'm basing this on this article: [https://blog.ouseful.info/2009/05/18/using-google-spreadsheets-as-a-databace-with-the-google-visualisation-api-query-language/][1]

Now, in a query (split line for reading convenience)

```
https://spreadsheets.google.com/d/
13pXb7Kek010B6s8Ez3h6yX4qF92MgvV4uMk71dJhe3o/tq? 
tqx=out.html&tq=select+*+where+B+contains+%27Pine,%20Jack%27
```

And I get the following message:

```
google.visualization.Query.setResponse({
"version":"0.6","status":"error","errors
[{"reason":"access_denied","message":"Access
denied","detailed_message":"Access denied"}]});
```

Obviously I'm missing something here.  How do I troubleshoot this?

Comment: Went back to the article.  Tested some links.  Most don't work.  2009 that article was published.  So google has changed their parameters.

Comment: Actually they do work.  Just have to wait long enough.

Answer (score 0):

#### Google has changed something.  This answer no longer works

Added Sunday.

The following now will fetch the entire sheet:

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/
13pXb7Kek010B6s8Ez3h6yX4qF92MgvV4uMk71dJhe3o/
edit?tqx=out.html&tq=select+A,B,C,+where+A+starts+with+%27Pine%27#gid=0
```

But while it fetches, the select statement returns the entire sheet, or rather the query is ignored.

(I originally had %20's for all the +'s, but Google rewrote them, or my browser does.)

This method

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/
13pXb7Kek010B6s8Ez3h6yX4qF92MgvV4uMk71dJhe3o/
gviz/tq?tq=select%20A,B,C%20where%20A%20contains%20'Pine'#gid=0
```

returns a file json.txt. I don't read JSON, but sliding over the brackets and punctuation the content is there.

Note the difference around gviz/tq...

Google rewrites the URL removing tq? from it.

I cannot leave the tqx=out.html in place. I get no JSON file and a 'file unavailable error.'

Turns out what I need is tqx=out:html   Colon, not period.

Found the information in a table labeled "Request Format" in the document

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/dev/implementing_data_source